# Struts form bean objects creation and connection pooling

Tags: java, web-applications, struts

The question below was asked to me in one of the interview:

The interviewer gave me a scenario of a web application made in `Struts 1.0` as I had mentioned struts 1.0 in my resume. Its an application where people are registering themselves. He asked me what all I should do to make this in struts.

I told him that we have a PersonRegistration Action class & one form bean that contain all the fields present on the Registration Form. Business Layer and DAO layer.

Question he had asked me were:

> 1) If 1000 registration requests are coming at a time, how many form
>   bean objects will be created?
>
> 2) How many connections you need to keep if you use connection pool in
>   this case?
>
> 3) How many instances of PersonRegisration Action class will be created?

**Please share your answers with me.**

My Answer was: In the first case 1000 objects will be created and
For the second question, we need to test it by varying the connection pool size.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Struts 1 Actions are singletons therefore they must be thread-safe because only one instance of a class handles all the requests for that Action. The singleton strategy restricts to Struts 1 Actions and requires extra care to make the action resources thread safe or synchronized while developing an application.

**means only one instances of PersonRegisration Action**

Comment: any idea regarding the number of object of form bean?